# What does it mean by "Standard state" when calculating for standard heat of formation

Tags: thermodynamics

For example for this reaction:

Step 1: $\ce{CO(g) + 2H2(g) -> CH3OH(l)}$

Step 2: $\ce{CH3OH(l) -> CH4(g) + 0.5 O2(g)}$

for step 1, when computing the standard heat of formation

H = H($\ce{CH3OH}$) - H($\ce{CO}$)

I don't include hydrogen gas because its "element is in its standard state so H=0".

What does it mean by standard state and how would I know ?

Comment: Please format sentences properly, checking spelling and grammar.

Comment: This is the first time I see Phoenician alphabet used in physical chemistry. It's cool and all, but the text should be written from right to left, if you want to go full proto.